# Get src width and height from iframe in variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, iframe

hope someone can help me here.
I have a variable with an iframe in it, like this.

```
var iframe = '<iframe src="http://someaddress.com" width="600" height="500"></iframe>';
```

And i want to get the src, width and height, out of the variable, and into their own variables. I know i can use regular expression to it, but i can´t figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var iframe = '<iframe src="http://someaddress.com" width="600" height="500"></iframe>',
    regEx = /(src|width|height)=["']([^"']*)["']/gi;

iframe.replace(regEx, function(all, type, value) {
    console.log(type); // src/width/height
    console.log(value); //url/600/500
});
```